# Variable substitution JSF Resource Bundle property file

Tags: jsf, resourcebundle

Can i do something like in JSF Resource Bundle property text file:

```
receptionContact=Reception
reservationContact=Reservation

receptionEmail={receptionContact}
reservationEmail={reservationContact}
```

Comment: Did you find an answer ?

Answer (score 2):

You can [parameterize](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/I18N/ResourceBundlewithParameters.htm) your resource bundles, but no reflective reuse of values by keys. Please have a look on this:
https://code.google.com/p/reflectiveresourcebundle/

With that, you don't have repeat your self!

**Without:**

```
company.service.phone=555-1212
company.service.email=help@company.com
my.error.message=Problem accessing account!\
                 Please call customer service at 555-1212 \
                 or email us at help@company.com
```

**With:**

```
company.service.phone=555-1212
company.service.email=help@company.com
my.error.message=Problem accessing account!\
                 Please call customer service at ${company.service.phone} \
                 or email us at ${company.service.email}
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/index.html) is another interesting tutorial about formatting.

Comment: Yes. I've used this to learn how to use a custom resource bundle in jsf: http://www.andygibson.net/blog/article/resource-bundles-in-jsf-2-0-applications/

Comment: Hi buddy, i think you might have gotten my question wrongly, i am trying to reuse text from the resource bundle itself.

Comment: @ChinBoon: actually he _is_ answering your question - but you need the library in https://code.google.com/p/reflectiveresourcebundle/